# Display multiple images in one uiimageview

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to display multiple images in one uiimageview, one by one. But it onyly display the last image.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[scrollView addSubview:image];
[scrollView bringSubviewToFront:image];

for (int i = 0; i < [fileArr count]; i++) {

NSArray *fileNameArr = [[fileArr objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if (![[fileNameArr lastObject] isEqualToString:@"cfg"]) {

        check=line;
        NSString *msg = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Opening image: %@\n",[fileArr objectAtIndex:i]]];

        [textView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:msg waitUntilDone:NO];

        line=line+1;

//specify the image path, open the image file with UIImage library
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",jfm,[fileArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString *imageFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
        NSLog(@"----------------------------");
        NSLog(@"ImageFile: %@\n",imageFile);
        NSLog(@"Interger value: %i\n",i);

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile];

        NSLog(@"Image Width: %f", myImage.size.width);
        NSLog(@"Image height: %f", myImage.size.height);

        //if image failed to open
        if (myImage == nil) {
                    ...
                    ...
                   }
            else{
            //[image setImage:myImage];
            image.image = myImage;
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:7]; 
    }
           [image release];
           line=line+1;
           [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Maybe this [tutorial](http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-show-animation-in-iphoneipad-app.html) is similar to your question. U'll need to use animation to show all the images, one-by-one.

Comment: I need to also check the information of the images in the array one by one.If I use animation how can I check the information of the images individually?

Comment: As in I need to get the height and width of each image by opening them individually using a for loop.

Comment: yes, you can get this information about all the images from the imageArray which you'll be giving to the UIImageView.

Comment: I do not want to use animation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just add them as subviews (the other images) with UIVIew:addSubView. However I'm not positive that's what your looking for.